# How can I retrieve the value of a key in a HashMap that is a list in Clojure?

Tags: string, clojure, hashmap

I'm looking to retrieve a value given the key which is a list.

```
    (defn string-tuple [my-string]
      (partition 2 1 my-string))

    (defn split-and-frequent-tuple [lines]
      (frequencies (string-tuple lines)))

    (defn split-and-frequent [lines]
      (frequencies lines))

(defn string-split [my-string]
  (str/split my-string #" "))


    (def string-pairs (split-and-frequent-tuple (string-split "<s> I am Sam </s> <s> Sam I am </s> <s> I do not like green eggs and ham </s>")))

    ;; Calculate that bigram probability
    (println string-pairs)
    (println (string-pairs '(green eggs)))
```

Basically, string-pairs counts the frequencies of the number of items something like (green eggs) appears in a text. However, when I try to retrieve the key using something like `(string-pairs '(green eggs))` I always get `nil` back even though the map shows there is a value of 1 for that key.

I was just wondering where I am going wrong, I've tried everything `:(`

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `println` to display values, strings and symbols look the same, even though they are not equal.

When you are debugging, use `prn` which unambiguously shows values, or use `pr-str` to generate the string `pr` or `prn` would use, inside your `println` call.

This should give you the correct result (vectors and lists are equal in Clojure if their contents are equal).

```
(string-pairs ["green" "eggs"])
```

Comment: OMG, thank you so much! :D I will accept as soon as possible.

Comment: another argument for using prn: `{":a 0" ":b 1"}` is a valid hash map, but println makes it look like something completely different (but also valid). This isn't just a theoretical concern, strings containing spaces show up in hash maps quite regularly in my code at least.